# Remove-CalendarEvents fails when using -ErrorAction STOP

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

When using Remove-CalendarEvents -PreviewOnly I can retrieve meeting events, and even delete them on test accounts. However when I add -ErrorAction Stop to the command I get new errors on AD accounts that previously did not throw any errors.

The try\catch block is used to catch errors thrown when a user's mailbox cannot be found. And this part works. However the try\catch also catches a new error:

```
The "ErrorAction" parameter can't be used on the "Remove-CalendarEvents" cmdlet because it isn't present in the role definition for the current user. Check
the management roles assigned to you, and try again.
At C:\Users\O365ExchangeAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_waex0o3a.tea\tmp_waex0o3a.tea.psm1:55507 char:9
+         $steppablePipeline.End()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Remove-CalendarEvents], CmdletAccessDeniedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=CY4PR0101MB2935,RequestId=ba4d86db-d362-432d-9892-4ea92b503356,TimeStamp=7/18/2019 7:18:03 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-C
   mdletAccessDeniedException] 896C46A1,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.RemoveCalendarEvents
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

When I remove the -ErrorAction STOP parameter, the command completes successfully, and lets me view meeting events. However if I don't have -ErrorAction STOP then I cannot log when my script fails on an account because it doesn't have a mailbox.

```bsh
Try{
    $output = Remove-EXOCalendarEvents -Identity $user.UserPrincipalName -QueryStartDate (Get-Date) -PreviewOnly -CancelOrganizedMeetings -Confirm:$false
}Catch [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException] {
    LogWrite "$($user.Name) could not be found, most likely they do not have a mailbox"
}
```

Also removing the [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException] does not change the results.

Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Check if you're allowed to use this parameter on that command. Use two cmdlets from [that article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps#use-powershell-to-find-the-permissions-required-to-run-a-cmdlet)

Comment: Looking at the ManagementRoleEntry I do not have access to ErrorAction. I won't be able to update this until tomorrow, but I will and try again. Thanks for the comment, this looks like it will work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you have received is saying that you're not authorized to run that command with that specific parameter. In Exchange Server, such permissions are managed by using Management Roles. You can check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps) to learn more.

To check if you're able to run any cmdlet with specific parameter you can use the following script:

```bsh
# Define what you're looking for
$user   = 'john.doe@contoso.com'
$cmdlet = 'Remove-CalendarEvents'
$param  = 'ErrorAction'

# Find all your assignments
$assignments = Get-ManagementRoleAssignment -RoleAssignee $user -Delegating $false

# Find cmdlets you can run and filter only the one you specified
$assignments.role | Foreach-Object {Get-ManagementRoleEntry "$_\*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $cmdlet -and $_.Parameters -contains $param}}
```

In last line we're iterating all the roles assigned to you and checking role entries. Their format is `RoleName\CmdletName` so we're using `*` (wildcard) to get all. After last pipeline you're filtering only the results you want using [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6).

Comment: This is the answer, unfortunately it is more difficult to make new management role with these permissions than i expected. We ended up changing the script to not need the -ErrorAction Stop parameter. Thanks for the info though, learned quite a bit just from reading Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: Came across the same issue.  I also didn't bother changing permissions.  Instead I'm using this: if ($error[0].categoryinfo.activity -eq "Remove-CalendarEvents") after the call.